# Can $f_n\to f$ uniformly, $f'_n\to g$ uniformly, but $f$ not being differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Just the question in the title,

I know that if $f_n$ are differentiable, $f_n\to f$ uniformly, $f'_n\to g$ uniformly and $f$ is differentiable, then $f'=g$, so I'm looking for a counterexample if we remove that hypothesis.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the question and what you know...aren't you implicitly assuming that $f_n$ is differentiable  since $f_n^\prime$ exists and converges to $g$ uniformly...

Comment: @SarahPalinsAnger I'm not assuming the differentiability of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the following stronger result holds:

> If $f_n$ are differentiable functions on some open set $U$, $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $U$, and $f'_n\to g$ uniformly on $U$, then $f$ is differentiable on $U$ and $f'=g$ on $U$.

So there is no counterexample.

Comment: It is even enough that $(f'_n)$ converges on every compact of $U$ and $(f_n)$ converges at a single point $x_0\in U$.

Comment: What allows for this stronger condition i.e relaxation from uniform convergence to pointwise convergence?

Comment: Nice!  So the limit $f_n\to f$ does not even need to be uniform? Could you provide a proof/reference?

Comment: In fact, one only needs $\{f_n(x)\}$ to converge for some $x\in U$ to prove the same result (existence of $f$, etc). @YoTengoUnLCD See Theorem 7.17 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis by W. Rudin.